# Recovering from messed up binfmts configuration

Tags: executable

All I'm trying to do is getting a manually installed mono (to /opt/mono-2.10) to run CLI executables without having to specify the interpreter explicitly. Wine is **not** installed.

Ubuntu 10.10. No mono package is currently installed (`dpkg -l | grep mono` gives nothing), but they were in the past before I realized that I need a much newer one, so that's probably the source of this mess.

Running a CLI executable gives me this:

```
Can't exec "/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli": No such file or directory at /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors line 92.
```

That is correct, `/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli` does not exist and I don't know where it should have come from.

So I googled a bit and found some information about the binfmt_misc module. Indeed, it is loaded and I have a `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli` which contains this:

```
enabled
interpreter /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags:
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

This `run-detectors` script is Perl, but apparently doesn't work (this is probably [Debian #575776](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575776)):

```
user@host:/$ /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors
Use of uninitialized value in open at /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/binfmt-support/run-detectors line 56.
run-detectors: unable to open : No such file or directory
```

But anyway, I don't have Wine, so I don't need all that binfmt-detector-cli stuff in the first place. I just want those binaries to be hard linked with the Mono interpreter. I found [this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/180112/why-is-ubuntu-trying-to-open-my-mono-app-with-wine-instead-of-mono/180226#180226) and [this blog entry](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=92), which discuss how to change these rules. Unfortunately, trying that, I always get a 'permission denied':

```
user@host:/$ sudo echo .:CLR:M::MZ::/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono:. > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
bash: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Permission denied
user@host:/$ sudo echo -1 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli
bash: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli: Permission denied
```

I found `/usr/share/binfmts/cli` and changed it to

```
package mono-runtime
interpreter /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono
magic MZ
```

but that seems to have no effect. Then there is `/var/lib/binfmts/cli`, which I changed to

```
mono-runtime
magic
0
MZ

/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono
```

but that also has no effect. I also found the script `update-binfmts` but I can't get it to work. I don't even manage to remove an existing configuration. The following attempt for example leaves me with a rather cryptic error message:

```
user@host:/$ sudo update-binfmts --remove cli /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono
update-binfmts: warning: current package is <local>, but binary format already
installed by mono-runtime ; not removing.
```

I have no idea whether my arguments were valid (the help page mentions `<path>` but doesn't say the path to what it wants... or why), whether the second line is supposed to be an error message and whether it changed anything in the first place.

How do I make any executable that starts with the magic string 'MZ' to be run with `/opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono`?

---

Update 1: The outputs to the commands Colin suggested:

```
user@host:/$ sudo update-binfmts --package mono-runtime --remove cli /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono
update-binfmts: warning: current package is mono-runtime, but binary format
already installed by mono-runtime ; not removing.
user@host:/$ dpkg -S /usr/share/binfmts/cli
dpkg: /usr/share/binfmts/cli not found.
user@host:/$ sudo rm /usr/share/binfmts/cli*
user@host:/$ sudo update-binfmts --install cli /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono --magic MZ
update-binfmts: warning: current package is <local>, but binary format already
installed by mono-runtime
update-binfmts: exiting due to previous errors
```

Comment: If you have 300rep, please retag this with 'binfmts'. I can't create the tag myself and 'executable' was just a stopgap solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never edit `/var/lib/binfmts/cli` by hand.  That's a state file for `update-binfmts`.  You may have confused it by doing so, although I suspect the mono packages were buggy in the first place to have left things in this condition.  Plus, there's a trailing space confusing matters.

I'd recommend clearing out state first:

`update-binfmts --package 'mono-runtime ' --remove cli /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono`

Then check whether /usr/share/binfmts/cli is owned by any package (`dpkg -S /usr/share/binfmts/cli` - I don't think it should be, as you don't have mono-runtime installed), and if not then remove that file.

Then install the binary format properly, as a locally-installed format rather than one owned by a package:

`update-binfmts --install cli /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono --magic MZ`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. Unfortunately, I still can't convince `update-binfmts` to do anything and I just can't make any sense of its responses. They have been added as Update 1 on the question.

Comment: You've managed to tell update-binfmts that an interpreter is owned by a package name ending in a space, which is indeed bound to be confusing.  (I fixed this in binfmt-support 1.2.19; trailing spaces are now automatically stripped.)  I've edited the first command in my answer to account for this.

Comment: Brilliant, that fixed it. Both commands now completed successfully and CLI executables can be invoked without any warnings or errors. Thanks so much!