# binfmt-detector-cli from mono-runtime does not recognize x64 executables?

Tags: 14.04, executable, mono, binary

On 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, I can apparently run "x86" exe files, but not "x64" ones.

If I use monodevelop to build the x86 configuration of a project, resulting in `x86/test.exe`, I can run it with `./x86/test.exe`, but if I instead build the x64 configuration resulting in `./x86/test.exe`, I cannot run it with `./x64/test.exe` - I get an error:

```
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./x64/test.exe
```

I can run both fine if I prefix the command with `mono` (`mono ./x64/test.exe` and `/usr/bin/cli ./x64/test.exe` both work fine).

I can see that mono is configured to run these kinds of binaries:

```
$ update-binfmts --display   
...                                       
cli (enabled):                                                                                                                 
     package = mono-runtime                                                                                                    
        type = magic                                                                                                           
      offset = 0                                                                                                               
       magic = MZ                                                                                                              
        mask =                                                                                                                 
 interpreter = /usr/bin/cli                                                                                                    
    detector = /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli
```

Both of the files appear to begin with `MZ`:

```
$ head ./x86/test.exe
MZ\220^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@\377\377^@^@\270^@...

$ head ./x64/test.exe                  
MZ\220^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@\377\377^@^@\270^@...
```

But binfmt-detector-cli fails to detect one of them:

```
$ /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli ./x86/test.exe; echo $?                                                                                                               
0                                                           

$ /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli ./x64/test.exe; echo $?                                                                                                               
1
```

More information about the exe files:

```
$ file ./x86/test.exe                    
./x86/test.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows            

$ file ./x64/test.exe                
./x64/bin/ShapeSearch.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

I don't really understand what I'm talking about, unfortunately. I started this investigation by reading [Recovering from messed up binfmts configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34707/recovering-from-messed-up-binfmts-configuration), but it's a little bit over my head.

Comment: Are you using 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it's 64-bit Ubuntu. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: OK, then I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2015 the `binfmt-detector-cli` failed to accept the "PE32+" (i.e, x64) executable, so implicitly they were all filtered as "not CLR binary".  That was "fixed" in early 2022 with https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-mono/pull/35.  However, the result of the change is that most PE32+ files (CLR or not) were now tagged as "CLR binary" (sort of inverting the bug).

I have a proposal to fix the detector in https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-mono/pull/38.  I believe this change understands the differences between PE32 and PE32+.  Basically the "CLR Runtime Data Directory" entry is in a different location in the two formats.

NOTE: There are three levels of "binary" here.  The MS-DOS executable with the "MZ" file magic header registered with the kernel.  Embedded in that is a suite of "PE" headers.  For the CLR-relevant formats, there are 32-bit and 64-bit (ish) variations of called "PE32" and "PE32+".  Finally there is a header (sometimes called the "CLR Runtime Data Directory entry") that says if the executable content are CLR-managed-runtime binary data or native binary data.